# smart-location-lib not working on api level 21 and above android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using smart location library. I am trying to get location using longitude and latitude. But my code is working perfectly in api 16. but I checked it on api 21. the same code isnt showing anything.. nor crashing. I have added permissions but still isnt working.
Kindly check this out. Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

I have used this library: https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Double lat;
private Double lon;
private Context context;
private Button address_button;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =11 ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;
    address_button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_address);



    address_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Call Permission")
                                .setMessage("Hi there! We can't access locationanyone without the Location permission, could you please grant it?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Yep", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ":(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                        }
                                }).show();
                    }else {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                } else{
                    SmartLocationCityName();
                }
            }else{
                SmartLocationCityName();
            }

        }




        });




}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SmartLocation.with(context).location().stop();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode== PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            SmartLocationCityName();
        }
    }
}

public void SmartLocationCityName(){
    SmartLocation.with(context).location()
            .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {



                @Override
                public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {

                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(context,lat+" "+lon+" ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
                        String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                        String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

                        Toast.makeText(context,lat+" "+lon+" "+cityName+"-"+"-"+stateName+"-"+countryName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch (IOException ex){

                    }


                }
            });

}
```

}

Comment: Were you able to debug this issue?

Comment: no I was not able to figure it out.